# Implementing POP3 server with Python

Tags: python, pop3

I have no experience doing anything like this, but I want to make a little email server that will only be accessed from the local machine through the Mail app in OS X. I know that the Mail app lets you connect to an email server with the POP3 protocol, and I have a reference manual on POP3 so I know how it all needs to work. I am just not sure of the best way to write this. I know python has smtpd, which I can use for receiving mail from the Mail app. Can I just use the SocketServer module, subclass BaseRequestHandler, read from the self.request socket until I get a CRLF, split the data by spaces, then use the first item in the list as keyword and apply the corresponding function to the rest of the list, and finally return the status + results? Or is it more complicated than that?

**--EDIT--** 
I forgot to mention that I wanted to do this in pure python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pypopper](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/534131-pypopper-python-pop3-server/) python recipe to readily implement the pop3 server functionality.

Comment: `poplib` is for a _client_ not a server.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - Right you are. See updated answer.

Comment: Is there a reason this doesn't use the SocketServer module?

Comment: @Broseph - SocketServer module is a different way of implementing the same thing as this pypopper script. I guess pypopper is not using the SocketServer module for obvious performance reasons - The socket object could be used to listen on a port at much lower level, thus bettering the performance.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing protocols and a working server is always more complicated than "just a few lines of code". Try [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) It has implementations for many internet protocols and working examples. Here's an example: http://pepijndevos.nl/twisted-pop3-example-server/